# My code will not execute in wordpress, even though I've been told the code is fine

Tags: javascript

I am battling with a problem for months now, that my code will not execute or show the result, when I enqueue it. I have been told, that my code is fine, and that it should work.
The clock is showing, so the css and html is correct, but not doing anything.
Here it is:

```
<?php

function childtheme_parent_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'parent', get_template_directory_uri().'css/style.css' );
function mytheme_files() {
 wp_enqueue_style('mytheme_main_style', get_stylesheet_uri());
wp_register_script('main-js', get_stylesheet_directory_url() . '/js/main.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme_parent_styles');

wp_register_script('main-js',get_stylesheet_directory_url().'/js/main.js');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pr_scripts_styles' );
}

function pr_scripts_styles() {
if( is_page(507) ) {
wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js');      


}
```

The js code is in a folder named js and in a file named main.js

```
setInterval(() => {
    d = new Date(); //object of date()
    hr = d.getHours();
    min = d.getMinutes();
    sec = d.getSeconds();
    hr_rotation = 30 * hr + min / 2; //converting current time
    min_rotation = 6 * min;
    sec_rotation = 6 * sec;
  
    hour.style.transform = `rotate(${hr_rotation}deg)`;
    minute.style.transform = `rotate(${min_rotation}deg)`;
    second.style.transform = `rotate(${sec_rotation}deg)`;
}, 1000);
```

```php
<?php

function childtheme_parent_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent', get_template_directory_urI().'/css/style.css' );
    function mytheme_files() {
        wp_enqueue_style('mytheme_main_style', get_stylesheet_uri());
        wp_register_script('main-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme_parent_styles');

    wp_register_script('main-js',get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/main.js');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pr_scripts_styles' );
}

function pr_scripts_styles() {
    if( is_page(507) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js');
    }
```

Will check the dev tools.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, I will let you know tommorow if it works.

Comment: function childtheme_parent_styles() { wp_enqueue_style( 'parent', get_template_directory_urI().'/css/style.css' );
function mytheme_files() { wp_enqueue_style('mytheme_main_style', get_stylesheet_uri());
wp_register_script('main-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');
} add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme_parent_styles'); wp_register_script('main-js',get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/main.js'); } add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pr_scripts_styles' );
} function pr_scripts_styles() {
if( is_page(507) ) {
wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js'); } Will check the dev tools.

Comment: Is the PHP code the entire code? There's a missing `}` at the end, also where is the code? Which file is it in. If there is an error it will show in your PHP error log, have you checked? And when you say the code doesn't run, do you mean it fails? Or the page crashes? Or there's an error? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Use the `edit` link underneath the tags in your question to update it, rather than posting updated code as the solution to your question. This isn't a discussion forum so people will see you responded to your own question and assume you were posting the solution

Comment: I also strongly recommend indenting the code correctly to avoid problems, there are a number of problems that are hidden by the lack of indentation

Comment: I updated the last snippet you posted and added indentation and it's clear there are major PHP syntax issues, such as nested functions, brackets that don't match up ( `{` and `}` ), and hooks that add themselves inside themselves so they would never run, and functions that are started but never finished

Comment: @SpencerHalstead I've revised your PHP. Give it a shot now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors I see in your code. First is that you've written `get_stylesheet_directory_url()` instead of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`. Switch the `L` for an `I` and that will probably fix it.

Second, for the JS file you're adding a slash before the folder, and for the CSS you're not. Once you fix the URL/I issue, you may still need to remove the `/`

**Update**
I've reviewed and updated your enqueue styles. There were a number of issues, but I've tightened it up, and this will load your styles and scripts:

```
function childtheme_parent_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('parent', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('mytheme_main_style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_register_script('main-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');
    if( is_page(507) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js');
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme_parent_styles');
```

Good luck!

Comment: No, it still does not execute. I put the i in and tried it with a small i and capital i.  I also put a slash on the css and js, and tried them without the slashes.

Comment: Have you checked dev tools to confirm that the file itself is loading? That's the first step.

And being able to see the code in place will help a lot for solving the problem.

Comment: @Pixelsmith check the PHP code, it's got a lot of basic syntax errors and mistakes

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks! I thought I'd start with the obvious stuff! :D

Comment: Where would I find the php error log. Must I look for a file called php_ini configuration file.